# Transmission is using a weirdo file browser instead of my default kde file browser

Tags: linux, debian, kde, transmission, dolphin-file-manager

I just install Debian Lenny with KDE.

In transmission when I right click a torrent and choose "open folder" it opens in Baobab then I need to right click the file and choose "Open folder" to finally open it in Dolphin (my file browser).

On Windows it just opens in Windows Explorer (the default file browser).

How can I get it to do this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's baobab data usage analyser. Your problem is not specific to KDE. I'm on XFCE w/ Debian 10 with the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's from KDE, i got the same problem but it was rather simple to fix.
Just go to System Configuration > Applications > Defaults Applications > File Explorer

Change it to another explorer than Dolphin (ex: Konqueror) and apply.
Change it back to Dolphin than apply.

Did the trick for me.
(it could be from a KDE update and a reset of settings idk)

Tested on Arch Linux with KDE 5.7.3

Comment: The same works for me on Debian 10 and XFCE. You don't need to change to another file explorer there, it can be an arbitrary application. As I have no other file explorer installed I've chosen the first file I've found in /usr/bin (7z). After changing back to thunar it worked as expected. Thanks.

Comment: @ArpadHorvath What did you do with xfce/debian? I'm having the same issue as OP but the file manager is set to Thunar in Settings->Prefered Applications

Comment: @user3728501 I have Thunar too as default file manager. But earlier Transmission opened the folder with Baobab even if the default file manager was Thunar.

Comment: @ArpadHorvath Yes... what I'm asking is how do you fix this?

Comment: @user3728501 I use XFCE in Hungarian, but the screen shot might help you https://pyedu.hu/tmp/thunar_as_default.png. Yes after Settings->Prefered Applications A changed thunar to something else (don't need to be file manager at all), than changed back, and worked properly.

Comment: @ArpadHorvath Ok thanks, I didn't understand that it needed to be changed then "changed back" again, thanks

Answer (score 0):

@user626084's answer worked for me, but I was curious why. Did a little more digging and found a useful link: [Non-KDE (GTK?) apps ignore KDE "Default Applications" and launch the wrong web browser](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/non-kde-gtk-apps-ignore-kde-default-applications-and-launch-the-wrong-web-browser/128443)

`sayan1` writes: `try editing mimeapps.list in .config or in .local/share/applications.`

I looked inside my `mimeapps.list` it was in `~/.config`.

```
[Added Associations]
...
inode/directory=org.kde.dolphin.desktop;     
...

[Default Applications]
...
inode/directory=org.kde.dolphin.desktop;
...
```

Last edit time was when I followed @user626084's steps.

Using Rui Ribeiro's tip: [How to find what programs are reading my file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370401/258248) you can see which processes are accessing the `mimeapps.list` file.

`sudo sysdig -A -c echo_fds "fd.filename=mimeapps.list"`

You get something like:

```
------ Read 968B from   /home/igq/.config/mimeapps.list (systemsettings5)
...
...
...
------ Read 969B from   /home/igq/.config/mimeapps.list (kbuildsycoca5)
...
...
...
```

[kbuildsycoca5 (8) - Linux Man Pages](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-kbuildsycoca5/)
`kbuildsycoca5: Rebuilds the KService desktop file system configuration cache.`

Comment: PS: Am using kubuntu 21.10